# Fetch only one of each entry based on date

Tags: sql-server, webmatrix, razor-2

Im currently working with SQL Compact 4 and Razor and im trying to fetch only one of each entry based on latest date

`id Name Number LastDate
 1  Joe  1111   2014-01-01
 2  Sam  2222   2014-01-02
 3  Joe  1111   2014-04-11
 4  Sam  2222   2014-04-12
 5  Lee  3333   2014-04-12`

I'm trying to write the data out to a webgrid but i can't find the correct SQL statement to only load id 3, 4 and 5 since they are the last updated entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT id, Name, Number, LastDate FROM yourTable t1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Number, MAX(LastDate) AS MaxDate FROM yourTable GROUP BY Number) t2
ON t1.Number = t2.Number AND t1.LastDate = t2.MaxDate
```

Comment: That one worked like a charm! Thanks a lot you saved some hair on my head this day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one query:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.number = t.number and
                        t2.lastdate > t.lastdate
                 );
```

This implements the logic:  "Get me all rows from `t` where there is no row with the same `number` and a later `lastdate`".

Comment: Thanks for the comment, now i have two working queries!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work (assuming you want the last record by the "Number" column and that there are no duplicate dates by number):

```
select max(lastdate) as lastdate, number into #temp
from t
group by number

select * from #temp t1
inner join t on t.number = t1.number and t.lastdate = t1.lastdate
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01357/5

(Thinking about this further, even if there were duplicate dates by number, the only field that would differ would be the id column which you could perhaps take the MAX of depending on your requirements.)

Comment: This code generate an error "System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 42,Token in error = into ]"

Comment: And yes you are correct i only want to display the last record of number

Comment: Looks like SQL CE doesn't support temporary tables.  My mistake.  You could always wrap the query that creates the temporary table into a subquery which should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() in the OVER statement like this:

```
select id, name, number, lastdate
from
(
  select 
    id, name, number, lastdate,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY LastDate DESC) as dateord
  from table
) t
where t.dateord = 1
```

Comment: I tried it and i do not belive this SQL command work on SQL Compact 4, it generate and error
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = OVER ]

Comment: @Tman You are right: ROW_NUMBER doesn't exist in SQL Server Compact Edition.

Comment: @Tman - won't work on all versions -- but on versions it works on can be marginally faster.